# Typo3 files not found

Tags: css, typo3, http-status-code-404

I have set up a Typo3 project and I am using the Bootstrap Kickstart Package extension. So far everything works, but for example the CSS files are not loaded (see screenshot). If I call the paths in Explorer, all files are available. Can someone here help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the .htaccess of TYPO3? You can find it in the typo3_src folder and move it to your root directory. Without it, the timestamps of the files ?12345 will be interpreted wrong.

Comment: I have a .htaccess file in my root folder.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it could not get a proper path to the assets. Please check your baseUrl and absRefPrefix
    in the setup ts. Check property below:

```
config.baseURL = http://localhost/project/
config.absRefPrefix = project/
```

Generally, absRefPrefix required in the local server it does not require at the live server.

Second possibility permission issue, please check directory permission.

Hope this helps you!

Greetings!

Comment: config.baseURL and config.absRefPrefix are missing in my setup.ts.

Comment: It's not resolved. They are missing, but adding them takes no effect.